# Google maps markers not showing in explorer or chrome

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, maps

I'm following the tutorial on how to use google maps with php/mysql here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Everything looks ok in Firefox, but the markers are not showing in Chrome or Explorer. In the chrome console I get he following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null /maps/:35
(anonymous function) /maps/:35
request.onreadystatechange

Here's my code (exactly the same as in the tutorial):

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>

 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    
key=AIzaSyAGdu4GFzdG3B203KSHApI5hA9HQmGKRrc&sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

 var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
 };

 function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>


<body onload="load()">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's the file outputting the xml:

```
<?php  

require("db.php"); 

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ('maps', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while (( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))!==false){

// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
$marker = $dom->createElement("marker");  
 $node->appendChild($marker);   
 $marker->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
 $marker->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);  
 $marker->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
 $marker->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
 $marker->setAttribute("type", $row['type']); 
 }

 echo $dom->saveXML();

 ?>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the problems that duncan already pointed out, you cannot do

```
  var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
```

because there are no associative arrays in Javascript. var customIcons is defined as an object, therefore

```
var icon = eval('customIcons'+'.'+type) || {};
```

Then, the icon parameter of the Marker object should be a MarkerImage object, so instead of

```
icon: icon.icon,
shadow: icon.shadow,
```

you should use

```
icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon.icon),
shadow: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon.shadow),
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out for me. I've made the changes you suggested. However, it did not solve my problem. Still get the same error. Do you have av working script?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a working copy of *your script*. However, if you care to post a link to what you have we could debug it properly. Note that the error you're getting refers to the line var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");  so it is possible that your XML is not loading correctly.

Comment: I thought maybe you hade tried the same tutorial (link above), and that's why I asked. Here's the live site using the script posted above: http://gjutveckling.se/maps/ and here's the xml output: http://gjutveckling.se/maps/genxml.php Thank's for helping :)

Comment: Your problem seems to be in your PHP. Try clicking the link you posted for your XML with Chrome, (empty page), and then view the source of that empty page. The PHP script is sending the wrong headers. You need to send a proper XML header before the output begins, so in the PHP script you need header('Content-Type: text/XML'); See: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_server.asp In addition to that, note that many of the markers have lat/lon (0,0)

Comment: Sorry about the empty page, I've been trying different things. You are absolutely right, while debugging I had only text in the content-type definition. I get another error messaged in chrome now, but the markers are showing: http://gjutveckling.se/maps/ Thank's a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1):

```
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
```

This is not a valid map type.  It should be like this instead:

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

This isn't quite right either:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
```

It should be like this instead:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Comment: And you need a body too, I reckon.

Comment: @Pete: Yes, I just left the body part out, but I've put it in the sample code now. Duncan: I tried your suggestions but the markers still doesn't show and the error in the console is still there.